# Query Cache utilisation ~50% Qcache_lowmem_prunes still high

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-cache

I ran two tests, each running for about a week

## Test 1

#### Query Cache Settings

- query_cache_limit: **50K**
- query_cache_size: **128M**
- query_cache_min_res_unit: **1K**

#### Results

- Qcache_free_blocks: **6,004**
- Qcache_free_memory: **93,598,504**
- Qcache_hits: **377,204,411**
- Qcache_inserts: **13,056,941**
- Qcache_lowmem_prunes: **384,610**
- Qcache_not_cached: **5,794,907**
- Qcache_queries_in_cache: **16,006**
- Qcache_total_blocks: **38,724**

#### Results (Calculated Values)

- Utilisation: **40.7%**
- Removal Ratio: **2.9%**
- Hit Rate: **95.2%**
- AVG Query Size: **4,012**
- Frag Indicator: **15.5%**

*Utilisation = 100-Qcache_free_memory*100/query_cache_size

Removal Ratio = Qcache_lowmem_prunes*100/Qcache_inserts

Hit Rate = Qcache_hits*100/(Qcache_hits+Qcache_inserts+Qcache_not_cached)

AVG Query Size = (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache

Frag Indicator = Qcache_free_blocks*100/Qcache_total_blocks*

## Test 2

#### Query Cache Settings

same as above except

- query_cache_min_res_unit: **2K**

#### Results

- Qcache_free_blocks: **1,287**
- Qcache_free_memory: **70,082,320**
- Qcache_hits: **223,742,107**
- Qcache_inserts: **7,104,530**
- Qcache_lowmem_prunes: **186,235**
- Qcache_not_cached: **3,218,864**
- Qcache_queries_in_cache: **20,802**
- Qcache_total_blocks: **43,424**

#### Results (Calculated Values)

- Utilisation: **55.6%**
- Removal Ratio: **2.6%**
- Hit Rate: **95.6%**
- AVG Query Size: **4,217**
- Frag Indicator: **3.0%**

## now for the question....

As expected, when I lowered query_cache_min_res_unit, fragmentation went up. What really has me confused is why is the removal ratio still so high even when utilisation is low?

Comment: The metrics for the QC are mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

To use least amount of QC space, use

```
query_cache_min_res_unit=512
```

for less waste of QC RAM  and qcache_lowmem_prunes expected to decrease as well over time.